# Class not found inside Namespace in WPF Component Library Project

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

In one of my WPF component library project, i have added the following line in my WPF component file -

```
xmlns:behaviours="clr-namespace:MyTextBox.Behaviours"
```

And inside the UserControl tag i have used the below reference -

```
<behaviours:PutCursorAtEndTextBoxBehavior />
```

But I'm getting the below error -

```
The name "PutCursorAtEndTextBoxBehavior" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MyTextBox.Behaviours"
```

MyTextBox 
  |_ Behaviours
      |_ PutCursorAtEndTextBoxBehavior.cs

I have restarted and reopened the project for several times. Am I doing something wrong ?

**Edit :**
Here is my PutCursorAtEndTextBoxBehavior -

```
Namespace MyTextBox.Behaviours
{
    class PutCursorAtEndTextBoxBehavior : Behavior<UIElement>
    {
        private TextBox _textBox;

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();

            _textBox = AssociatedObject as TextBox;

            if (_textBox == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            _textBox.GotFocus += TextBoxGotFocus;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            if (_textBox == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            _textBox.GotFocus -= TextBoxGotFocus;

            base.OnDetaching();
        }

        private void TextBoxGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
        {
            _textBox.CaretIndex = _textBox.Text.Length;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you show the PutCursorAtEndTextBoxBehavior class

Comment: Try to make it public PutCursorAtEndTextBoxBehavior

Comment: @bit: Did that. The result is same. In the xmal file when i'm pressing ctrl+space inside "behaviours" tag its showing me the class name but when I'm placing the classname there, the error is still there.

Comment: Did you change the namespace? It reads VizAutoNewsTextBox.Behaviours at the moment. Shouldn't you be using that instead?

Comment: Check it now . Namespace is not an issue there. I have corrected my namespace. check it in main question.

Comment: Have you tried building the project?

Comment: @hantoun : Yes. the result is same.

Comment: This project was inside a solution. I pulled out the project from the solution and place it in somewhere else. After that opened the project from new location . Its working now. That means inside the solution it was not getting the namespace correctly. How did that happen

Comment: It was my mistake. It was due to error in lib reference add. I have resolve the error in library reference. Now its working perfectly. Thank you all for your time.